# I am trying to understand if this situation will trigger memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a simple code that fetch data from DB. i am using helper method for pagination and i want to know if this situation will memory leak:

```
function getData(page) {
    if (!page) { page = 1; }
    return db.getData().then(function (data) {
        return formatResults(data, page);
    });
}

function formatResults(data, page) {
    return {
        data: data, // 50MB Data for each page
        nextPage: getData.bind(null, page + 1)
    };
}

getData().then(function (result) { // RUN RECURSIVELY 100,000 TIMES
    console.log(result.data);
    result.nextPage().then(...); // MEMOERY LEAK IN formatResults???
});
```

Comment: Why do you suspect it might?

Comment: Because nextPage lives in formatResults, so i care that it will exists there forever (Imagine that i run nextPage() recursively million times...)

Comment: It's not really recursing because it's using promises. So each function exits and its local data is cleaned up before the next call executes. And eventually it will reach the last page, and then all the functions exit.